# Slow Converting from JsonArray to ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, json

I have to convert a JsonArray to an ArrayList but unfortunately the code below is used very often during the execution of the program! How can I speed it up?

**Java:**

```
public static ArrayList CastJsonObject(JSONArray object) {
        ArrayList<Cantiere> tm = new ArrayList<Cantiere>();
        Cantiere cant;
        Cliente c;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < object.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject value = object.getJSONObject(i);
                int IdCantiere = Integer.parseInt(value.getString("IdCantiere").toString());
                int IdCliente = Integer.parseInt(value.getString("IdCliente").toString());
                String Filiale = value.getString("Filiale").toString();
                String RagioneSociale = value.getString("RagioneSociale").toString();
                String NomeCantiere = value.getString("NomeCantiere").toString();
                String DataCreazioneCantiere = value.getString("DataCreazioneCantiere").toString();
                String Tipologia = value.getString("Tipologia").toString();
                String StatoCantiere = value.getString("StatoCantiere").toString();
                int StatoFatturazione = Integer.parseInt(value.getString("StatoFatturazione").toString());
                c = new Cliente(IdCliente, RagioneSociale, Filiale);
                cant = new Cantiere(c, IdCantiere, NomeCantiere, DataCreazioneCantiere, Tipologia, StatoCantiere, StatoFatturazione);
                tm.add(cant);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("\n Error: " + ex);
        }

        return tm;
    }
```

Comment: It would help us a lot if you added an example of the data you're parsing. `JSONObject` also looks like this is about adroid...

Comment: And I have one question: why do you always call `toString` if you already got one with `getString`?

Comment: @t3chb0t So you're right for tostring! I find it hard to bring you an example on JSONArray since it is a value that comes back from a node.js server which performs a search, so each time the values ​​are different! It may be useful to implement the streams in java

Comment: When I just do "open type" in my eclipse and enter "JSONArray" (with the capitals in the beginning) I find no less than 9 different libraries which contain such a class. Care to tell us which one you use? (Or post the import statements.)

Comment: I use this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there really is a performance problem with that code, please back this up with some measurements. Otherwise, read some articles concerning premature optimization and don't bother.

Nevertheless, on micro-level there are a few calls that you don't need:

Get rid of superfluous .toString() calls, e.g. replace

```
String Filiale = value.getString("Filiale").toString();
```

with

```
String Filiale = value.getString("Filiale"); // this already is a string
```

Similarly, don't parse the integers yourself after converting them to string, but instead call `getInt()` on the Json object:

```
int IdCantiere = value.getInt("IdCantiere");
```

Avoid the repeated call to `object.length()` by holding the length in a variable:

```
for(int i = 0, n = object.length(); i < n; i++)
```

Still, the code should be relatively fast as-is. Naturally, there's no way to be really sure without knowing what the constructors for Cliente and Cantiere actually do. If you have a real performance problem, introduce measurements aroud the parameter extraction and the object construction.

And: measure BEFORE AND AFTER you change the code as shown above so that you actually know what effect it had. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java for some advice on how to do this.

Comment: thank you very much! is much faster, now I try to make a check with the benchmarks to your link and see what happens